# Left arrow html and css

Tags: html, css

I need code for this functionality.
By default, it should be like right headed arrow [image: Right arrow] and when i click it should be down headed arrow.[image: down arrow]

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: You cannot do that by only using HTML and CSS. As this involves clicking, you would also need js/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using javascript. If you don't know how to use javascript, refer to the code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript>
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById('img').src = "down.jpg";
}
</script>

<body>
<img src="right.jpg" id="img" onclick="myFunction();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Enjoy :D

As you can see, we fetch the element in js using its id and change its src attribute and set it to your another image. You can change the event which is onclick as per your needs. You can use ondblclick to trigger the function on double click. ^-^

Answer (score 0):

This may help you @pbrc1995 :)

```js
function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the Menu Icon to transform it to "X":</p>
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not asking for a JavaScript solution, here's one without it.

```css
div.arrow {
  width:33px; height:30px;
  background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMatp.png');
}

div.arrow:active{
  width:51px; height:26px;
  background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3Bew.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```